# Templating an all form in detail on same page template

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I need to display a form with complex HTML structure in my custom module. And not a single field had the same wrapper structure.

So I need more flexibility in my template `custom.html.twig` than just `{{ form }}`. How can I do that?

The actual markup is the following.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    {{ form }}
</div>
```

The needed markup is the following.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ form.action }}" method="{{ form.method }}"" id="{{form.id }}"">
        <div class="form-group" id="{{ form.field1.id }}">
            <div class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ form.field1.label }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-8>{{ form.field1.input }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="{{ form.field2.id }}">
            <div class="col-md-6 control-label">{{ form.field2.label }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-6>{{ form.field2.input }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="{{ form.field3.id }}">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2>{{ form.field3.input }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="edit-submit">
            {{ form.submit }}
        </div>
    <form>
</div>
```